# Structuring PHP code to link object creation and db writes?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, design-patterns, pdo

I am writing a site (PHP + MySQL) where some objects (say, articles) are organized in sets.  Each article belong to a singleton set.  Each set can be stand alone or belong to a larger set.  A set is either a singleton or it is a collection of sets.  To keep track of the relationships between the sets, I use a closure table that tracks all "family links".  The table has an `ancestor` field, a `descendant` field, and a `length` field which counts the degrees of separation between the ancestor and the descendant.

- Each new article implies the creation of a new singleton set.
- Each new set implies the creation of a new closure table entry where `ancestor` and `descendant` are the same and where `length`=0.  New sets can be created independently of articles since sets can be collection of existing sets.

I want to structure my PHP program so that each time I write a new article in the db, I automatically write a new set, and each time I load a new set, I automatically write a new closure table entry.

What is the right way to structure my code?  Is it to create nested objects (the `article` object includes a `set`, which itself include a `closure`) and a recursive function to write on the database which would write the nested object first (and where the end condition would be if the object is a closure table entry)?  Is there a way to fold those recursive writes inside a single transaction?

Is there an existing pattern I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward. The nested objects are somewhat correct but in reverse order.

Look at it in a is-a relation. An article is part of a set, but in one set can be multiple articles. A set can be part of another set, but in this other set can be multiple lower sets. The lower should not know the higher.

**How does the structure look like?**

```
CREATE TABLE article (
    articleID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    // some other columns that don't matter for this structure answer
);

CREATE TABLE set (
    setID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    // some other columns that don't matter
);

CREATE TABLE article_to_set (
    articleID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    setID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (articleID, setID)
);

CREATE TABLE set_to_set (
    setID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    parentSetID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (setID, parentSetID)
);
```

**How are the PHP classes structured?**

The `Set` knows from database if an article belongs to it (standalone set) or other sets (collection of sets). So it has two properties. The first is a nullable article reference variable and the second an array of the sub-set objects (can be empty).
The `Article` knows from database only it's own properties and it does know nothing from the relation to any set.

**How is the linking handled?**

If you create an article in the controller `ArticleAdd`, you create the article and a standalone set. Then you insert a row with both the articleID and the setID into the table `article_to_set`. 
If you create a new set `a` without an article, it is empty on begin. If you then add new sets (direct or via articles), you can put them into the set `a` by adding rows to the table `set_to_set`, where the `parentSetID` is the ID of the set `a` and setID the ID of the set you put into the set `a`.

This solution doesn't use a closure table but it makes the design much better for future edits. And putting one set into another can easily be done by adding one row.